# What should I do with the neutral line while running 3-Phase induction motor?

Tags: motor, ac, three-phase, induction-motor

As far as I've seen, low voltage distribution lines (3-Phase 440 volts) have four wires - three phases and one neutral (Ignore the earth cable). What should I do with the neutral line if I want to run an induction motor with a Delta-Star starter? I know that the delta connection does not need neutral. But in Star connection, should I connect the Neutral with the common terminal of the Star?

Online documents and books have ignored the neutral line. As far as I know, the output of the distribution transformer (11KV Delta / 440 Wye) sometimes gets unbalanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I know, the output of the distribution transformer (11 kV Delta / 440 Wye) sometimes gets unbalanced.

That would be a very good reason **not** to connect the motor star / wye point to neutral. The motor - if all is well with the windings - will have its star / wye point centred between the three phases. Connecting this to neutral may result in uneven voltages applied to the motor's three windings.

Answer (score 3):

N is not used from the source in a Squirrel Cage Motor (SCM) .

Rather a 3P2T transfer switch is used only from the 3Ph Delta source to boost the voltage per windings in Star Mode with <50% rated load torque for starting then switched to Delta across each pair for Run mode to reduce excitation currents and improve PF.

[image] [ref](https://electricalworkbook.com/star-delta-starter/)

There are plenty of Youtube video explanations too.